# Ajax replacing parent span instead of creating child

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, innerhtml

I'm trying to make something that will add to a list of videos, three items at a time at the click of a button, from MySQL. Rather than use jQuery, I decided to try and get clever with AJAX.

What is supposed to happen is the page loads, and three videos from the database are loaded, followed by a span. The span has a button to activate a script, a script to send a request to retrieve 3 new items and a button, and a value of 0. You press the button, and 3 new items and a new span, with a new button and script, replace the old button. This way, to the user it looks like there are three items and a button, then you click the button and there are 6 items and the same button, then 9 and a button, etc.

Here's the code for the page that loads:

```
$newVideos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newVideos)) {
        echo '<br> The video "'.$row["title"].'"';
    }
    ?>


<span id="newvideos">
<br><button onclick="newvideos(this.value)" value="0">More Videos</button><br>
<script>
function newvideos(x) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("newvideos").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","videosearch.php?morevideos="+x,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</span>
```

And this is what that script is sending a request to:

```
if (isset($_GET['morevideos'])) {
    $morevideos = $_GET['morevideos'];
    if (isset($morevideos)) {

        $y = 3 + $morevideos;
        $newVideos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$y.",3");
        //DESC is descending, last to first
        //ASC is ascending, first to last

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newVideos)) {
            echo '<br> The video "'.$row["title"].'"';
        }
        echo '<span id="newvideos'.$y.'">';
        echo '<br><button onclick="newvideos(this.value)" value="'.$y.'">More Videos</button><br>';
        ?>

        <script>
        function newvideos(x) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("newvideos<?php echo $y; ?>").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","videosearch.php?morevideos="+x,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>
        </span>
        <?php

    }

}
?>
```

So what happens instead is that when the first button is clicked, the first button is replaced with 3 new video items, a new script, and a new button inside of a span called `"newvideos3"`. And the script says to replace the innerhtml of an element with the ID `"newvideos3"`. But what happens instead is the still existing parent "newvideos" span is replaced instead with videos 7-9 and a `"newvideos6"` span, rather than all that being appended to the list. Why, when the script says to replace `"newvideos3"`, would this happen?

I also tried going directly to videosearch.php?morevideos=0, and the videos from `"newvideos3"` loaded. I clicked the button and the next videos, 7-9 and a new button, were appended to the list. Then I clicked that new button, and 7-9 were replaced.

Is there some policy or rule about innerhtml replacing parent nodes when scripts are generated from other scripts or something, and I just don't know about it?

**UPDATE**

I've made some revisions based on comments by barmar (thanks!), however it still doesn't work. It seems the script was, indeed, not being updated. Here is the revised code.

This is what the user sees loaded:

```
$newVideos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3");
    //DESC is descending, last to first
    //ASC is ascending, first to last

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newVideos)) {
        echo '<br> The video "'.$row["title"].'"';
    }
    ?>


<span id="newvideos">
<br><button onclick="fetchvideos(this.value)" value="0">More Videos</button><br>
<script>
function fetchvideos(x) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("newvideos").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","videosearch.php?morevideos="+x,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</span>
```

And here is what the request is sent to:

```
if (isset($_GET['morevideos'])) {
    $morevideos = $_GET['morevideos'];
    if (isset($morevideos)) {

        $y = 3 + $morevideos;
        $newVideos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$y.",3");
        //DESC is descending, last to first
        //ASC is ascending, first to last

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newVideos)) {
            echo '<br> The video "'.$row["title"].'"';
        }
        echo '<span id="newvideos'.$y.'">';
        ?>
        <br><button onclick="fetchvideos<?php echo $y; ?>(this.value, 'newvideos<?php echo $y; ?>')"  value="<?php echo $y; ?>">More Videos</button><br>';

        <script>
         function fetchvideos<?php echo $y; ?>(x, z) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById(z).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","videosearch.php?morevideos="+x,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>
        </span>
        <?php
         }

}
```

Now that the newly generated script is renamed to something different, the web console says that the function **fetchvideos3** doesn't exist. It appears that html is not updated with AJAX. Inspector shows that the script is added to the page, but the debugger does not show that the script is added. I would think that since the new script isn't added that the button calling the new script shouldn't technically be able to call the script either, don't really understand that.

I've also given everything a unique, generated name, and made it so onclick and the new functions use 2 arguments instead of one. How do I get the newly generated from AJAX scripts to run?

Comment: Assigning to `.innerHTML` doesn't run any scripts in the HTML. So the `newvideos` script isn't being redefined.

Comment: Why don't you just add another argument to `newvideos()` function that contains the ID of the DIV to put them in. So the original button contains `onclick="newvideos(this.value, 'newvideos')"`, and when you load the AJAX the button contains `onclick="newvideos(this.value, 'newvideos3')"`

Comment: Also, don't use the same name for a function as the ID of a DOM element. IDs get turned into global variables, and so are top-level functions, so one of them will replace the other.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Thanks! Unfortunately it still doesn't work, but the issue seems clearer now. Is there a way to make the newly generated, now uniquely named, scripts to run? I've updated the original post.

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to run the scripts without using jQuery.

Comment: mmmmmm. Ok, I may have to use it. Why is it that the frontend page obviously updates with new information, but the actual html, including scripts, doesn't? Maybe I'm new to this (and I am), but I don't understand where the new code AJAX delivers is being stored and read from if the original response from the server isn't being updated.

Comment: The HTML returned by AJAX is still being added to the DOM. It just doesn't execute any of the Javascript within it. So it doesn't define the `newvideos$y()` function.